# Stroke Width Transformation (SWT) using Liuliu

Tags: text, computer-vision, detection

I'm using https://github.com/liuliu/ccv for text detection in business cards. The problem is that the recall is low and a good amount of text in the business cards is missed - sometimes partially and at times completely. Can anyone suggest values for the parameters in the file `swtdetect.c` that could give high recall? I can compromise on the precision.

Comment: A matlab implementation (based on C++ mex file) can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19971599/1714410)