# what's the common way for segmenting a text from an image using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, text-extraction, image-segmentation, matlab-cvst

I have searched about this field and I found some papers that present new methods to extracting texts from images, but I have a grayscale image consists of a simple background and some texts.so I need a method that everyone works with it.
please provide details on how this can be done.

Comment: Maybe have a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960826/how-to-make-the-blackboard-text-appear-clearer-using-matlab/19962240?noredirect=1#comment29743737_19962240)

Comment: [The article](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/text_detection.pdf)

Comment: for example "Text detection and recognition in natural images" by Steven Bell that presents a method without performing segmentation.

Comment: this article seems to be for natural images only but my images as i said have very simple background for example a red background with probably some noises. do you think this paper will help me?

Comment: @top.eng You should try reading the paper describing the stroke width transform. If it works for complicated backgrounds it should work in your case as well.

Comment: If you look to the first link I send, the guys use this paper on a blackboard, as you, it a uniform background. Have a look closer, I don't know if it good for you or not.

Comment: @top.eng morover since you already have an implementation of SWT - why don't you just give it a try?

Comment: thank guys.I will read the paper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an article about text segmentation.

the [article](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/text_detection.pdf)

And here an easy way to segment your image in 2 class.

```
I = imread('...'); % Your board image
ThreshConstant = 1; % Try to vary this constant.

bw = im2bw(I , ThreshConstant * graythresh(I)); % Black-white image

SegmentedImg = I.*repmat(uint8(bw), [1 1 3]);
```

Just do `imshow(bw);` and you will have a 2 color image normally well segmented.

If the threshold is too strong, try to turn around 0.5 to 1.5 with `ThreshConstant`.

Comment: I tried your answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2049859/top-eng?tab=reputation) and helped me. if you post it here i want to mark it as my answer.

Comment: The BW or the SWT article ? Whatever, I Edit my answer

Comment: You're welcome. But this is a simple ostu 2-class segmentation. If you maybe look for more class segmentation. This [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26532-image-segmentation-using-otsu-thresholding) is really good.