# Extracting number from an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

Basically I need to extract the identification number of marathon runners from the image. Till now I was able to get the bib part alone from the whole image. Now I need to extract the numbers from that image:

[image]

I need to extract 1430 from the image. I have tried some methods like OCR and blob detection techniques but they are not successfull for all images.

Comment: Somehow the picture is not loaded currently. Is imgur down? Also please specify what exactly you have used (which OCR and which blob detection technique) and show us the image where these have not been successfull. Obviously these images are the problem.

Comment: The question is not really too broad, given the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Stroke Width Transform (SWT)](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/text_detection.pdf)? You can find a Matlab implementation of the first stages of SWT [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19971599/1714410).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html) in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.

Comment: I tried that, ocr detects only text with proper background. In my case the background is not uniform.

Comment: Did you just try the ocr() function or the whole example.  The example segments out the text, so you can use that to clean up the background.

Comment: Yeah I tried that it is not giving any ouput.